# OrientDB - Create map from two different external properties

Tags: orientdb

I have one vertex connected to other vertices as:

```
B1 <------E1------ A1 ------E2------> B2
      name=name1        name=name2
```

Vertex A1 of class A has several properties.
Edges E1 and E2 are of class and each have a name property.

I want a query to return Vertex A1 but with a map of the connected vertices' rids as keys and the name on their respective edge as values.

**I.e, I want to return:**

```
{
    <all of vertex A1's normal properties>,
    connected: {
        <ridB1>: name1,
        <ridB2>: name2 
    }
}
```

I know how to return this:

```
{
    <all of vertex A1's normal properties>,
    names: ["name1", "name2"],
    rids: ["ridB1", "ridB2"]
}
```

By doing:

```
SELECT *, out("E")[@rid] as rids, outE("E")[name] as names from #14:0
```

But I can't seem to be able to build the map I would like from the two lists.

Comment: Hi dargolith, which version of orientdb you have?

Comment: @ldacrema I would like to use the newest version released as docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select @rid, name from E where outV().name LIKE "%A1%"
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I mean no offense,  but you need to read the question again I think. I would like the whole A1 record with a map with keys of rids (B1's and B2's rids) and values as the property name from the edge connecting that specific record. See the desired output above.